# Optimisation of Arduino sketch -> using for or while loops instead of switch

Tags: loops, optimization, for-loop, arduino

I created an Arduino sketch, which I use to switch on or off two sets of LEDs. The idea of the program is to run in cycles with a certain number of steps in each cycle. So far, I have written the sketch in a way that I can define up to 12 different steps (see code below), however adding further steps is very complicated and needs many lines of code. I am wondering, if anyone of you could help in coming up with a way to replace my switch cases with a loop iterating over the individual steps. Since my programming skills are really basic, I am thankful for any suggestions for improving my code.

**Parameter definition for each step:**

```
unsigned long cycles = 1000;        // number of cycles
byte steps = 4;                     // number of steps to repeat in cycles
unsigned long timebasis = 1000;     // factor to multiply with ms to set time basis -> 1 results in 1 ms time basis, 1000 results in 1 s etc
//Step 1
#define s1_intensity_LEDcolor1 1000     // intensity 660 nm at step 1
#define s1_intensity_LEDcolor2 0        // intensity 740 nm at step 1
#define s1_duration 5               //length of step 1
//Step 2
#define s2_intensity_LEDcolor1 0        // intensity 660 nm at step 2
#define s2_intensity_LEDcolor2 0        // intensity 740 nm at step 2
#define s2_duration 2               // length of step 2
//Step 3
#define s3_intensity_LEDcolor1 0        // intensity 660 nm at step 3
#define s3_intensity_LEDcolor2 1000     // intensity 740 nm at step 3
#define s3_duration 1               // length of step 3
//Step 4
#define s4_intensity_LEDcolor1 0        // intensity 660 nm at step 4
#define s4_intensity_LEDcolor2 0        // intensity 740 nm at step 4
#define s4_duration 4               // length of step 4
//Step 5
#define s5_intensity_LEDcolor1 100      // intensity 660 nm at step 5
#define s5_intensity_LEDcolor2 1000     // intensity 740 nm at step 5
#define s5_duration 50              // length of step 5
//Step 6
#define s6_intensity_LEDcolor1 0        // intensity 660 nm at step 6
#define s6_intensity_LEDcolor2 1000     // intensity 740 nm at step 6
#define s6_duration 80              // length of step 6
//Step 7
#define s7_intensity_LEDcolor1 300      // intensity 660 nm at step 7
#define s7_intensity_LEDcolor2 0        // intensity 740 nm at step 7
#define s7_duration 50              // length of step 7
//Step 8
#define s8_intensity_LEDcolor1 0        // intensity 660 nm at step 8
#define s8_intensity_LEDcolor2 0        // intensity 740 nm at step 8
#define s8_duration 60              // length of step 8
//Step 9
#define s9_intensity_LEDcolor1 0        // intensity 660 nm at step 9
#define s9_intensity_LEDcolor2 1000     // intensity 740 nm at step 9
#define s9_duration 70              // length of step 9
//Step 10
#define s10_intensity_LEDcolor1 700     // intensity 660 nm at step 10
#define s10_intensity_LEDcolor2 0       // intensity 740 nm at step 10
#define s10_duration 30             // length of step 10
//Step 11
#define s11_intensity_LEDcolor1 0       // intensity 660 nm at step 11
#define s11_intensity_LEDcolor2 0       // intensity 740 nm at step 11
#define s11_duration 80             // length of step 11
//Step 12
#define s12_intensity_LEDcolor1 1000    // intensity 660 nm at step 12
#define s12_intensity_LEDcolor2 1000    // intensity 740 nm at step 12
#define s12_duration 90             // length of step 12

Timer1.initialize(timebasis*1000);  // setting the time base
Timer1.attachInterrupt(doSomething);   // execute function "doSomething" every X µs based on time base

void doSomething()
{
  counter++;
}
```

**Sum up individual step lengths:**

```
#define s1_dur s1_duration                
#define s2_dur (s1_duration + s2_duration)   
#define s3_dur (s1_duration + s2_duration + s3_duration)  
#define s4_dur (s1_duration + s2_duration + s3_duration + s4_duration)    
#define s5_dur (s1_duration + s2_duration + s3_duration + s4_duration + s5_duration)   
#define s6_dur (s1_duration + s2_duration + s3_duration + s4_duration + s5_duration + s6_duration)
#define s7_dur (s1_duration + s2_duration + s3_duration + s4_duration + s5_duration + s6_duration + s7_duration)
#define s8_dur (s1_duration + s2_duration + s3_duration + s4_duration + s5_duration + s6_duration + s7_duration + s8_duration)
#define s9_dur (s1_duration + s2_duration + s3_duration + s4_duration + s5_duration + s6_duration + s7_duration + s8_duration + s9_duration)
#define s10_dur (s1_duration + s2_duration + s3_duration + s4_duration + s5_duration + s6_duration + s7_duration + s8_duration + s9_duration + s10_duration)
#define s11_dur (s1_duration + s2_duration + s3_duration + s4_duration + s5_duration + s6_duration + s7_duration + s8_duration + s9_duration + s10_duration + s11_duration)
#define s12_dur (s1_duration + s2_duration + s3_duration + s4_duration + s5_duration + s6_duration + s7_duration + s8_duration + s9_duration + s10_duration + s11_duration + s12_duration)
```

**step functions:**

```
void step1()
{
    if(debug == 1)
    {
    time_unit(s1_duration);
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print("C1:");
    fill_up_4(s1_intensity_LEDcolor1);
    lcd.print(s1_intensity_LEDcolor1);
    lcd.print("|C2:");
    fill_up_4(s1_intensity_LEDcolor2);
    lcd.print(s1_intensity_LEDcolor2);
    }
    setColor(color1, s1_intensity_LEDcolor1);
    setColor(color2, s1_intensity_LEDcolor2);
}

void step2()
{
    if(debug == 1)
    {
      time_unit(s2_duration);
      lcd.setCursor(0,1);
      lcd.print("C1:");
      fill_up_4(s2_intensity_LEDcolor1);
      lcd.print(s2_intensity_LEDcolor1);
      lcd.print("|C2:");
      fill_up_4(s2_intensity_LEDcolor2);
      lcd.print(s2_intensity_LEDcolor2);
    }
    setColor(color1, s2_intensity_LEDcolor1);
    setColor(color2, s2_intensity_LEDcolor2);  
}

void step3()
{
    if(debug == 1)
    {
      time_unit(s3_duration);
      lcd.setCursor(0,1);
      lcd.print("C1:");
      fill_up_4(s3_intensity_LEDcolor1);
      lcd.print(s3_intensity_LEDcolor1);
      lcd.print("|C2:");
      fill_up_4(s3_intensity_LEDcolor2);
      lcd.print(s3_intensity_LEDcolor2);
    }
      setColor(color1, s3_intensity_LEDcolor1);
      setColor(color2, s3_intensity_LEDcolor2);  
}

void step4()
{
    if(debug == 1)
    {
      time_unit(s4_duration);
      lcd.setCursor(0,1);
      lcd.print("C1:");
      fill_up_4(s4_intensity_LEDcolor1);
      lcd.print(s4_intensity_LEDcolor1);
      lcd.print("|C2:");
      fill_up_4(s4_intensity_LEDcolor2);
      lcd.print(s4_intensity_LEDcolor2);
    }
      setColor(color1, s4_intensity_LEDcolor1);
      setColor(color2, s4_intensity_LEDcolor2);  
}

void step5()
{
    if(debug == 1)
    {
      time_unit(s5_duration);
      lcd.setCursor(0,1);
      lcd.print("C1:");
      fill_up_4(s5_intensity_LEDcolor1);
      lcd.print(s5_intensity_LEDcolor1);
      lcd.print("|C2:");
      fill_up_4(s5_intensity_LEDcolor2);
      lcd.print(s5_intensity_LEDcolor2);
    }
      setColor(color1, s5_intensity_LEDcolor1);
      setColor(color2, s5_intensity_LEDcolor2);  
}

void step6()
{
    if(debug == 1)
    {
      time_unit(s6_duration);
      lcd.setCursor(0,1);
      lcd.print("C1:");
      fill_up_4(s6_intensity_LEDcolor1);
      lcd.print(s6_intensity_LEDcolor1);
      lcd.print("|C2:");
      fill_up_4(s6_intensity_LEDcolor2);
      lcd.print(s6_intensity_LEDcolor2);
    }
      setColor(color1, s6_intensity_LEDcolor1);
      setColor(color2, s6_intensity_LEDcolor2);  
}
void step7()
{
    if(debug == 1)
    {
      time_unit(s7_duration);
      lcd.setCursor(0,1);
      lcd.print("C1:");
      fill_up_4(s7_intensity_LEDcolor1);
      lcd.print(s7_intensity_LEDcolor1);
      lcd.print("|C2:");
      fill_up_4(s7_intensity_LEDcolor2);
      lcd.print(s7_intensity_LEDcolor2);
    }
      setColor(color1, s7_intensity_LEDcolor1);
      setColor(color2, s7_intensity_LEDcolor2);  
}
void step8()
{
    if(debug == 1)
    {
      time_unit(s8_duration);
      lcd.setCursor(0,1);
      lcd.print("C1:");
      fill_up_4(s8_intensity_LEDcolor1);
      lcd.print(s8_intensity_LEDcolor1);
      lcd.print("|C2:");
      fill_up_4(s8_intensity_LEDcolor2);
      lcd.print(s8_intensity_LEDcolor2);
    }
      setColor(color1, s8_intensity_LEDcolor1);
      setColor(color2, s8_intensity_LEDcolor2);  
}
void step9()
{
    if(debug == 1)
    {
      time_unit(s9_duration);
      lcd.setCursor(0,1);
      lcd.print("C1:");
      fill_up_4(s9_intensity_LEDcolor1);
      lcd.print(s9_intensity_LEDcolor1);
      lcd.print("|C2:");
      fill_up_4(s9_intensity_LEDcolor2);
      lcd.print(s9_intensity_LEDcolor2);
    }
      setColor(color1, s9_intensity_LEDcolor1);
      setColor(color2, s9_intensity_LEDcolor2);  
}
void step10()
{
    if(debug == 1)
    {
      time_unit(s10_duration);
      lcd.setCursor(0,1);
      lcd.print("C1:");
      fill_up_4(s10_intensity_LEDcolor1);
      lcd.print(s10_intensity_LEDcolor1);
      lcd.print("|C2:");
      fill_up_4(s10_intensity_LEDcolor2);
      lcd.print(s10_intensity_LEDcolor2);
    }
      setColor(color1, s10_intensity_LEDcolor1);
      setColor(color2, s10_intensity_LEDcolor2);  
}
void step11()
{
    if(debug == 1)
    {
      time_unit(s11_duration);
      lcd.setCursor(0,1);
      lcd.print("C1:");
      fill_up_4(s11_intensity_LEDcolor1);
      lcd.print(s11_intensity_LEDcolor1);
      lcd.print("|C2:");
      fill_up_4(s11_intensity_LEDcolor2);
      lcd.print(s11_intensity_LEDcolor2);
    }
      setColor(color1, s11_intensity_LEDcolor1);
      setColor(color2, s11_intensity_LEDcolor2);  
}
void step12()
{
    if(debug == 1)
    {
      time_unit(s12_duration);
      lcd.setCursor(0,1);
      lcd.print("C1:");
      fill_up_4(s12_intensity_LEDcolor1);
      lcd.print(s12_intensity_LEDcolor1);
      lcd.print("|C2:");
      fill_up_4(s12_intensity_LEDcolor2);
      lcd.print(s12_intensity_LEDcolor2);
    }
      setColor(color1, s12_intensity_LEDcolor1);
      setColor(color2, s12_intensity_LEDcolor2);  
}
void laststep()
{
  setColor(color1, 0);
  setColor(color2, 0);
  counter = 0;
  cycle_counter++;
}
```

**Accessory functions:**

```
//----------------------- Checks digits of value and fills up to a total of 4 digits with spaces ------
void fill_up_4(int value_length)
{
  if(value_length < 10)              // value smaller 10, write 3 spaces to LCD
  {
    lcd.print("   ");
  }
  else if(value_length < 100)         // value smaller 100, write 2 spaces to LCD
  {
    lcd.print("  ");
  }            
  else if(value_length < 1000)        // value smaller 1000, write 1 spaces to LCD
  {
    lcd.print(" ");
  }
} 

//----------------------- Checks time value and sets time unit accordingly ------------------------
void time_unit(unsigned long time_value)
{
  unsigned long basecorrectedtime = time_value * timebasis;
  if(basecorrectedtime < 1000)              // value smaller 1 sec -> display in ms
  {
    lcd.print(basecorrectedtime/1000);
    lcd.print("ms");
  }
  else if(basecorrectedtime < 60000)         // value smaller 1 min -> display in sec
  {
    lcd.print(basecorrectedtime/(float)1000);           // (float) results in decimal numbers
    lcd.print(" s");
  }    
  else if(basecorrectedtime < 3600000)         // value smaller 1 hour -> display in min
  {
    lcd.print(basecorrectedtime/(float)60000);
    lcd.print(" m");
  }            
  else                               // value bigger than 1 hour, display in hours
  {
    lcd.print(basecorrectedtime/(float)3600000);
    lcd.print(" h");
  }
}
```

**Main switch case:**

```
switch(steps)
  {
    case 1:  switch(counter)            // 1 step program
    {
      case 0:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
          lcd.setCursor(0,0);
          lcd.print("St. 1/1| ");
        }
        step1();
        break;
      case s1_dur:
        laststep();
        break;
    }
    case 2: switch(counter)         // 2 step program
    {
      case 0:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
          lcd.setCursor(0,0);
          lcd.print("St. 1/2| ");
        }
        step1();
        break;
      case s1_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
          lcd.setCursor(0,0);
          lcd.print("St. 2/2| ");
        }
        step2();
        break;
      case s2_dur:
        laststep();
        break;
    }
    break;
      case 3: switch(counter)           // 3 step program
    {
      case 0:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
          lcd.setCursor(0,0);
          lcd.print("St. 1/3| ");
        }
        step1();
        break;
      case s1_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
          lcd.setCursor(0,0);
          lcd.print("St. 2/3| ");
        }
        step2();
        break;
      case s2_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
          lcd.setCursor(0,0);
          lcd.print("St. 3/3| ");
        }
        step3();
        break;        
      case s3_dur:
        laststep();
        break;
    }
    break;
      case 4: switch(counter)           // 4 step program
    {
      case 0:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
          lcd.setCursor(0,0);
          lcd.print("St. 1/4| ");
        }
        step1();
        break;
      case s1_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
          lcd.setCursor(0,0);
          lcd.print("St. 2/4| ");
        }
        step2();
        break;
      case s2_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
          lcd.setCursor(0,0);
          lcd.print("St. 3/4| ");
        }
        step3();
        break;
      case s3_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
          lcd.setCursor(0,0);
          lcd.print("St. 4/4| ");
        }
        step4();
        break;          
      case s4_dur:
        laststep();
        break;
    }
    break;
      case 5: switch(counter)           // 5 step program
    {
      case 0:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
          lcd.setCursor(0,0);
          lcd.print("St. 1/5| ");
        }
        step1();
        break;
      case s1_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
          lcd.setCursor(0,0);
          lcd.print("St. 2/5| ");
        }
        step2();
        break;
      case s2_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
          lcd.setCursor(0,0);
          lcd.print("St. 3/5| ");
        }
        step3();
        break;
      case s3_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
          lcd.setCursor(0,0);
          lcd.print("St. 4/5| ");
        }
        step4();
        break; 
      case s4_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
          lcd.setCursor(0,0);
          lcd.print("St. 5/5| ");
        }
        step5();
        break;              
      case s5_dur:
        laststep();
        break;
    }
    break;
      case 6: switch(counter)           // 6 step program
    {
      case 0:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
          lcd.setCursor(0,0);
          lcd.print("St. 1/6| ");
        }
        step1();
        break;
      case s1_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
          lcd.setCursor(0,0);
          lcd.print("St. 2/6| ");
        }
        step2();
        break;
      case s2_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
          lcd.setCursor(0,0);
          lcd.print("St. 3/6| ");
        }
        step3();
        break;
      case s3_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
          lcd.setCursor(0,0);
          lcd.print("St. 4/6| ");
        }
        step4();
        break; 
      case s4_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
          lcd.setCursor(0,0);
          lcd.print("St. 5/6| ");
        }
        step5();
        break;
      case s5_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
          lcd.setCursor(0,0);
          lcd.print("St. 6/6| ");
        }
        step6();
        break;         
      case s6_dur:
        laststep();
        break;
    }
    break; 
      case 7: switch(counter)           // 7 step program
    {
      case 0:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St. 1/7| ");
        }
        step1();
        break;
      case s1_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St. 2/7| ");
        }
        step2();
        break;
      case s2_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St. 3/7| ");
        }
        step3();
        break;
      case s3_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St. 4/7| ");
        }
        step4();
        break; 
      case s4_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St. 5/7| ");
        }
        step5();
        break;
      case s5_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St. 6/7| ");
        }
        step6();
        break;
      case s6_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St. 7/7| ");
        }
        step7();
        break;           
      case s7_dur:
        laststep();
        break;
    }
    break;
      case 8: switch(counter)           // 8 step program
    {
      case 0:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St. 1/8| ");
        }
        step1();
        break;
      case s1_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St. 2/8| ");
        }
        step2();
        break;
      case s2_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St. 3/8| ");
        }
        step3();
        break;
      case s3_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St. 4/8| ");
        }
        step4();
        break; 
      case s4_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St. 5/8| ");
        }
        step5();
        break;
      case s5_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St. 6/8| ");
        }
        step6();
        break;
      case s6_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St. 7/8| ");
        }
        step7();
        break; 
      case s7_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St. 8/8| ");
        }
        step8();
        break;         
      case s8_dur:
        laststep();
        break;
    }
    break; 
      case 9: switch(counter)           // 9 step program
    {
      case 0:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St. 1/9| ");
        }
        step1();
        break;
      case s1_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St. 2/9| ");
        }
        step2();
        break;
      case s2_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St. 3/9| ");
        }
        step3();
        break;
      case s3_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St. 4/9| ");
        }
        step4();
        break; 
      case s4_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St. 5/9| ");
        }
        step5();
        break;
      case s5_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St. 6/9| ");
        }
        step6();
        break;
      case s6_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St. 7/9| ");
        }
        step7();
        break; 
      case s7_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St. 8/9| ");
        }
        step8();
        break;
      case s8_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St. 9/9| ");
        }
        step9();
        break;        
      case s9_dur:
        laststep();
        break;
    }
    break;
      case 10: switch(counter)          // 10 step program
    {
      case 0:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St. 1/10|");
        }
        step1();
        break;
      case s1_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St. 2/10|");
        }
        step2();
        break;
      case s2_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St. 3/10|");
        }
        step3();
        break;
      case s3_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St. 4/10|");
        }
        step4();
        break; 
      case s4_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St. 5/10|");
        }
        step5();
        break;
      case s5_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St. 6/10|");
        }
        step6();
        break;
      case s6_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St. 7/10|");
        }
        step7();
        break; 
      case s7_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St. 8/10|");
        }
        step8();
        break;
      case s8_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St. 9/10|");
        }
        step9();
        break;
      case s9_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St.10/10|");
        }
        step10();
        break;          
      case s10_dur:
        laststep();
        break;
    }
    break; 
      case 11: switch(counter)          // 11 step program
    {
      case 0:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St. 1/11|");
        }
        step1();
        break;
      case s1_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St. 2/11|");
        }
        step2();
        break;
      case s2_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St. 3/11|");
        }
        step3();
        break;
      case s3_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St. 4/11|");
        }
        step4();
        break; 
      case s4_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St. 5/11|");
        }
        step5();
        break;
      case s5_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St. 6/11|");
        }
        step6();
        break;
      case s6_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St. 7/11|");
        }
        step7();
        break; 
      case s7_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St. 8/11|");
        }
        step8();
        break;
      case s8_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St. 9/11|");
        }
        step9();
        break;
      case s9_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St.10/11|");
        }
        step10();
        break; 
      case s10_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St.11/11|");
        }
        step11();
        break;        
      case s11_dur:
        laststep();
        break;
    }
    break; 
      case 12: switch(counter)          // 12 step program
    {
      case 0:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St. 1/12|");
        }
        step1();
        break;
      case s1_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St. 2/12|");
        }
        step2();
        break;
      case s2_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St. 3/12|");
        }
        step3();
        break;
      case s3_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St. 4/12|");
        }
        step4();
        break; 
      case s4_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St. 5/12|");
        }
        step5();
        break;
      case s5_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St. 6/12|");
        }
        step6();
        break;
      case s6_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St. 7/12|");
        }
        step7();
        break; 
      case s7_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St. 8/12|");
        }
        step8();
        break;
      case s8_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St. 9/12|");
        }
        step9();
        break;
      case s9_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St.10/12|");
        }
        step10();
        break; 
      case s10_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St.11/12|");
        }
        step11();
        break;
      case s11_dur:
        if(debug == 1)
        {
            lcd.setCursor(0,0);
            lcd.print("St.12/12|");
        }
        step12();
        break;        
      case s12_dur:
        laststep();
        break;
    }
    break;    
  }
```

**Thanks a lot in advance!**

ozy

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I won't go through all your code, but I'll try to give you some ideas.

If you want to use for loops you should use [arrays](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Array) instead of the defines. Something like:

```
#define NUMBER_OF_STEPS 12;

const int DURATION[NUMBER_OF_STEPS] = {   5,    2,    1, … };
const int COLOR1[NUMBER_OF_STEPS]   = {1000,    0,    0, … };
const int COLOR2[NUMBER_OF_STEPS]   = {   0,    0, 1000, … };
```

A sample for loop through all steps would look something like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_STEPS; i++){

    //do whatever…
    //set colors using the array
    setColor(color1, COLOR1[i] );
    setColor(color2, COLOR2[i] );
}
```

See the [Arduino Reference](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/HomePage) on [for statements](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/For).
There is also an example on for loops.

Now go and shrink your code :)

Comment: thank you elpoto for your suggestion. I actually already started to look into arrays in combination with for loops, but as I said my skills are still very limited ;)

Comment: Nevertheless, I understand the concept and I am working on implementing variable arrays in my code. However, one thing would be very handy, though I don't know if it is possible: Can you define variable names with a counter in the name? Something like `int varName_i`, where `i` is a number counted up in a loop?

Comment: If I understand what you mean, that is exactly what Arrays are for.
Did you read the Arduino reference on Arrays I linked above?
The array `int myInts[6];` can be accessed in a loop via `myInts[i]`